# C++ reinterpret cast is inconsistent

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I made a test program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Bug {
    private:
        char a[25];

    int& view (int i) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a[i]);}

    public:
        Bug () {}

        void overwrite () {
            view(a[0]) = 2;

            cout << "value of a[0] is: " << view(a[0]) << endl;
        }
};

int main () {
    Bug b;
    b.overwrite();

    return 0;
}
```

... where I'm testing the view function. Everything works as I'd expect; the value beginning at `a[0]` is 2, as the print statement in the void method shows.

However, I modify the program slightly:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Bug {
    private:
        int x;
        char a[25];

    int& view (int i) {
        return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a[i]);}

    public:
        Bug () {}

        void overwrite () {
            view(a[0]) = 2;

            cout << "value of a[0] is: " << view(a[0]) << endl;
        }
};

int main () {
    Bug b;
    b.overwrite();

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that I added a private member variable `int x`. This was the only change. The moment I do this, the print statement in the overwrite method no longer prints 2, as in the previous program -- it returns a garbage value (and sometimes the correct value, 2).

More importantly, sometimes the correct value will show, but the program will segfault.

Anybody know what's happening under the hood?

Bonus question. for values lower than 25, my private variable char a[value] will show compiler warnings that mention stack smashing (using g++-4.7).

Comment: either change name of member variable to i_, or change the argument's name inside `int& view` to something else, and see if it helps

Comment: it interprets the 4 bytes at the same address as a[i] as an integer. So, what you get depends on how the data is initialized in the next 3 bytes (in the second case, that's the bytes occupied by i which is not initialized). BTW, the value of i as the parameter of the view method is probably not what you think.

Comment: This is seriously broken code that summons plenty of nasal demons. You violate strict aliasing, and you have no guarantee that the `char` array is properly aligned for an `int`.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29

Comment: @ComeRaczy: "it interprets the 4 bytes at the same address as a[i] as an integer". Yes, that makes perfect sense. You say that in the second case, the bytes occupied by i, which are not initialized, is what I get. Could you elaborate on that? I'm not sure I'm following. I'm changing the private int i variable to int x to remove ambiguity.

Also, isn't the value of i as the parameter simply the starting index to the next three bytes?

Comment: Also, `view(a[0])` means that you are looking at the bytes at `a[a[0]]`, which almost certainly isn't a valid subscript especially as `a` isn't initialized.

Comment: Thank you @T.C.! I noticed this myself after looking it over.

Comment: @T.C.: And the nasal demons are joined by aural demons.